# Embarcadero Delphi Xe5 Ide Split in two

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, mydac

Hi guys i have just installed Mydac into my delphi xe5 Ide and when i started it up afterwards the entire IDE Changed. It has split in two in basic terms it looks alot like delphi 7 now.

When i compile the app i am working on. The IDE returns to what it normally looks like. But on application close it reverts back to two individual parts.

I have checked the tool palette, and all items usually in the IDE (they did no longer show) i can add them to the below form.(the form with my units and code).

Everything is normal except for how it looks. It is hard to describe but basically the entire code editor and all tools linked to it has separated. And the main menu bar now also has a tool palette (looks like D7 basically)

Anybody Know the cause for this?

[image: Screenshot Of the IDE]

**Update:**
The image below shows how the ide opens now.with the answer below i can change the ide back to normal. But i cannot keep the changes if i restart Delphi.
how can i make the changes permanent?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: how can i post it @Martyna? i wanted to but cant find the option

Comment: @MartynA i have added it. Thank you missed it on the first try.

Comment: Wow ... two palette bar ... very strange! What version of Mydac  do you use ?

Comment: @TridenT MyDac 8.1.4 For Delphi Xe5

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Saving_Desktop_Layouts

Comment: I think you need hammer and anvil to reset the palette layout :) Let's try the latest version of myDac (v8.3). It's compatible with DelphiXE6 but with previous version also.

Comment: @trident I do not have internet at home and i work their aswell so i have not been able to update my delphi on that pc. Thus the new version of MyDac does not work on it. I contacted them for a version that works without the delphi updates and this is what they sent me.

Comment: @RobKennedy 10 stars for effort but it did not solve my problem. When selecting debugging layout the IDE returned to 1 form. But no other IDE selection is 1 form. They are all split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the View menu, you will see an option named "Dock Edit Window".

This is enabled by default.  I think you have unintentionally turned it off.  Enable it again, and your display should go back to what you're used to.

[Dock Edit Window](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Dock_Edit_Window)

The old school component palette is a different matter.  Under View|Toolbars, see if you have Component selected.  I'm not sure when this was reintroduced since I don't use this any more.

[Enabling the Component Toolbar](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Enabling_the_Component_Toolbar)

I'm not so sure about the docking, but to make sure the rest of the desktop settings are preserved between sessions, go to Tools|Options|Environment Options and make sure Project Desktop is selected under Autosave Options.

[Autosave Project Desktop](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Environment_Options)

Comment: ok now we are making progress. That has merged it back together(i didnt touch it. i think the installer of mydac may have changed its value). The only thing now, is how to i get the top tool palette away again?

Comment: Do you have DDevExtensions installed?

Comment: no i don't. At least not that i am aware of. it was never there until i installed this  mydac software

Comment: ok yes. That was the problem. Now the only issue i have is that when i set my ide back the way it should be. it works perfectly. I saved the desktop as "marcel" and now if i close the application and re-open it. It opens as image above again. And even if i set the desktop to marcel it does not change.

Comment: One more edit.  This should probably be broken up into multiple questions.

Comment: You say that you can set your IDE to look as it should. Now once you do this save that as "Default Layout". Now the name of the desktop layout needs to be "Default Layout". Don't save that as "marcel" as that layout isn't loaded by Delphi by default.

Comment: @SilverWarior: You can set any saved desktop as your default.  You just need to make sure the project desktop is auto saved.

Comment: @BruceMcGee Doesent desktop layout auto saving only saves desktop layout for that particular project? Meaning that when you open some other project it probably won't have same desktop layout.

Comment: @SilverWarior: I don't think so, but I only clearly remember trying it with no project loaded. Give it a try yourself.

Comment: @BruceMcGee No it only autosaves current IDE desktop layout for specific project. It does not change the default IDE layout. You need to do this on your own by saving it into "Default Layout". Just tested it out. And if you look at documentation link you posted you will se that Autosaving Desktop Layout creates a .dsk file in project directoy which is then read when opening that specific projects. Things that get saved into it are Desktop layout, Breakpoints, Watch items and Curently opened files. So it is there to alow you to easier pick up the work where you left it.

Comment: After a long struggle the problem has been solved. I just needed to save the desktop layout aswell and that seemed to solve the problem. Thank you guys!!